# Need guidancewith assignment scope and returns

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do an assignment and am quite stuck on one part of the assignment. Can you please help me and see what I am missing.

```js
// Example Code: Reference this code for the next Exercise
let school = 'Lambda';
let className = 'Intro to Web Dev'

function nameMySchool() {
  let className = "Web Development Fundamentals"
  console.log(school);
}

nameMySchool();
console.log(className);
// Do not change any code above this line!


// Exercise One: 
// Part One: Create a variable called 'inFunction' and 
//           assign it to the value that will be logged
//           on line 7.


// Part Two: Create a variable called 'outsideFunction' and
//           assign it to the value that will be logged on  
//           line 11.
const inFunction = ‘Lambda’

function nameMySchool() {

  const outsideFunction = ‘School’

  console.log(inFunction) // Lambda 

  console.log(outsideFunction) // School 

}
```

It always says infunction is not defined. I am so lost. Please help

Comment: _"It always says infunction is not defined."_. Can you please create a snippet to show that.

Comment: Don't use curly quotes in JavaScript programming, use straight quotes.

Comment: You can't access a `const variable` before it is `initialization`, try placing `const inFunction = 'Lambda'` before your `nameMySchool();`

Comment: @CodeManiac You shouldn't fix the bugs when you edit a question.

Comment: @codeManiac is it not before nameMyschool?

Comment: @Steele no it is not, you need to place before function call, the line where you're doing `nameMySchool();`